# How to add a new property to Json Object in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I want to add new properties in JSON object.

I did the following to get my result.

In MapJson.vb Class

```
Public Class MapJson
    Public Class item
        Public Property ColList As ColMap
    End Class

    Public Class ColMap
        Public Property inv As String
    End Class
End Class`
```

In a winform button click:

```
    Dim ColLst As New List(Of MapJson.ColMap)
    Dim ColItem As New MapJson.ColMap With {
       .inv = "ABC"
    }

    ColLst.Add(ColItem)

    Dim YearItem As New MapJson.item With {
        .ColList = ColLst.Single
    }
    Dim CreateNewJson As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(YearItem, Formatting.Indented)
    MsgBox(CreateNewJson)
```

The result I get is:

```
{
  "ColList": {
    "inv": "ABC"
  }
}
```

Now I want to add properties to `ColList` Object. 
Properties can be anything so I can't predefine it in the class.

I want something Like this :

```
{
  "ColList": {
    "inv": "ABC",
    "anyname1": "anyStringValue1",
    "anyname2": "anyStringValue1",
    "anyname3": "anyStringValue1"
  }
}
```

I searched internet and found this.

```
Dim jo As JObject = JObject.FromObject(jsontext)

jo.Add("feeClass", "A")
jo.Add("feeClass1", "B")
jo.Add("feeClass2", "C")
jo.Add("feeClass3", "D")

MsgBox(jo.ToString)
```

This works properly but I don't know how to add it to the ColList Object.
Thank you for you help in advance. :)

Comment: Can't you replace the ColMap class  by a Dictionary<string,string> ?

Comment: Can you give me an example how shall I do it? @RaimondKuipers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the property names ahead of time, you could just create an anonymous type to serialize:

```
 Dim YearItem = New With {
    .ColList = New With {
      .inv = "ABC"
      .anyname1 = "anyStringValue1"
      .anyname2 = "anyStringValue1"
      .anyname3 = "anyStringValue1"
    }
 }
```

Crucially, the first line of the code doesn't state `MapJson.item` etc, it just says `New With {`

You don't really need your classes with this, if all youre doing is creating them for serialization purposes, it's probably neater to just create an anonymous one

---

If you don't know them ahead of time, replace the ColMap with a dictionary:

```
Dim x = New With {
  .ColList = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
}

x.ColList.Add("inv", "ABC")
x.ColList.Add("anyname1", "anyStringValue1")
x.ColList.Add("anyname2", "anyStringValue1")
x.ColList.Add("anyname3", "anyStringValue1")
```

Though this example doesn't demo that (clearly I do know them ahead of time because it wrote them into the code).. perhaps a loop that adds a list will be used in production

---

PS if youre desperate to keep those classes:

```
Public Class MapJson
    Public Class item
        Public Property ColList As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    End Class
End Class`
```

Comment: I know that the ColList (name of the Object) exists. Ya bt I don't know its property name. So I try in your way using Dictionary and create it. Also, please check my answer I wrote. It worked for me.

Comment: I'm confused. Up to now you have seemed to be indicating that you DO know the name "ColList" - your answer even hard codes it. Now you are saying you don't know it? It's not a huge problem, it's just.. not really easy to write a program that "can receive and work with any json with any properties of any type and any name and any hierarchy" - time to ask for better JSON, really

Comment: No No No... Its Confusion here now.. I know ColList will be the name there.
But inside that object, there won't be any properties. All Properties were undefined.
Still. I am trying your way. Pleas wait for sometime..

Comment: You gave me a best answer. Now I will remove those classes. I don't need those classes anymore, Thanx alot. @Caius Jard

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found it myself.
Posting here as there is less question related to this out there.

What I did is:

Suppose jsontext is what you got result at first, i.e
Say,

```
jsontext = "{
  "ColList": {
    "inv": "ABC"
  }
}"
```

Later I did like this,

```
Dim NewJO As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsontext)
Dim NewSubJO As JObject = TryCast(NewJO("ColList"), JObject)
NewSubJO.Add("AA", "A")
NewSubJO.Add("BA", "B")
NewSubJO.Add("CA", "C")
MsgBox(NewJO.ToString)
```

And I got desired answer as

```
{
  "ColList": {
    "inv": "ABC",
    "AA": "A",
    "BA": "B",
    "CA": "C"
  }
}
```

I hope this helps to others :)